# Thread Wait and Wake up

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, wakeup

I'm trying to simulate a simple thermostat, using multi-threading. The thermostat should increase the temperature in order to reach the value that the user requested for which is "Max" value in the code below. I have two thread, one in charge of increasing the temperature and the other for decreasing it. but the condition for decreasing is it should be only running when the gas is off. 
but I have a problem with implementing this concept. as the code below runs, the second thread keeps throwing exception of null!

```
<pre><code>`private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
systemInitial();

Thread temperatureUp = new Thread() 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    while(true)
    {
        Max = Integer.parseInt(lblDesiredTemp.getText());
        Current = Integer.parseInt(lblCurrentTemp.getText());

            try
            {
                if(Max>Current)
                {
                    lblGasStatus.setText("On");
                    lblTemperatureSensor.setText("increasing");
                    increaseTemeture();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblGasStatus.setText("Off");
                    if(Current != 0)
                        lblTemperatureSensor.setText("decreasing");
                    else
                        lblTemperatureSensor.setText("----");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                txtLog.setText(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + txtLog.getText() );
            }
    }
    }
};

Thread systemUpdater = new Thread() 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            notifyGasBoiler(this);

            if(Current>0)
                decreaseTemeture();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            txtLog.setText(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + txtLog.getText() );
        }
    }
    }
};

    temperatureUp.start();
    systemUpdater.start();

}                                    

private synchronized void notifyGasBoiler(Thread gasOff) throws InterruptedException 
{
    try
    {
        if("On".equals(lblGasStatus.getText()))
        {
            gasOff.wait();
            txtLog.setText(txtLog.getText() + "\n" + gasOff.getName() + " waits.");
        }
        else
            notifyAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        txtLog.setText(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + txtLog.getText() );
    }
}`
```

what am I missing here?

UPDATE I:

this is the log I'm getting by running the system and request the 2 temperature:

Temperature increased to 1
Temperature increased to 2
null 
null
null
....

UPDATE II:

I used printStackTrace for exception and it got me this:

`java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at sol.smarthome.GUI.notifyGasBoiler(GUI.java:300)
    at sol.smarthome.GUI.access$900(GUI.java:14)
    at sol.smarthome.GUI$5.run(GUI.java:276)`

---

Update III

```
<pre><code>`private void btnUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    if(Max<=8)
    {
        Max++;
        String strI = String.valueOf(Max);
        lblDesiredTemp.setText(strI);
        setGasBoilerStatus();
    }
}                                     

private void btnDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    if(Max>0)
    {
        Max--;
        String strI = String.valueOf(Max);
        lblDesiredTemp.setText(strI);
        setGasBoilerStatus();
    }
}                                       

private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
systemInitial();

tempUp = new temperatureUp();
tempDown = new temperatureDown();

tempUp.start();
tempDown.start();
}                                    

private synchronized void increaseTemeture() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (monitor) {
    if (!getBoilerStatus()) 
    {
        tempUp.wait();
        //return;
    }
    else
    {

    Max = Integer.parseInt(lblDesiredTemp.getText());
    Current = Integer.parseInt(lblCurrentTemp.getText());

    if(Max>Current)
    {
        lblGasStatus.setText("On");
        lblTemperatureSensor.setText("increasing");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        Current ++;
        lblPumpStatus.setText("On");
        lblCurrentTemp.setText(String.valueOf(Current));
        txtLog.setText("Temperature increased to " + Current + "\n"+ txtLog.getText());
        if(Current>8)
            lblDanger.setVisible(true);
    }

    setGasBoilerStatus();

    if(!isGasOn)
    {
    try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        lblGasStatus.setText("Off");
        if(Current != 0)
            lblTemperatureSensor.setText("decreasing");
        else
            lblTemperatureSensor.setText("----");
    }
    }
    }

}

private synchronized void decreaseTemeture() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized (monitor) {
    if(getBoilerStatus())    
    {
        tempDown.wait();
        //return;
    }
    else
    {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    if(Current == 0 )
        return;

    Current --;
    lblCurrentTemp.setText(String.valueOf(Current));
    lblDanger.setVisible(false);
    txtLog.setText("Temperature decreased to " + Current + "\n"+ txtLog.getText());
    if(Current<1)
        lblPumpStatus.setText("Off");
    else
        lblPumpStatus.setText("On");

    setGasBoilerStatus();
    }
    }
}

private void systemInitial()
{
    lblDanger.setVisible(false);
    isPilotOn.setSelected(true);
    lblGasStatus.setText("Off");
    lblPumpStatus.setText("Off");
    isDone = true;
    isGasOn = false;
    Max = Current = 0;
}

// indicates if the boiler is on (true) or off (false)
// set as volatile to stop caching
private volatile boolean isBoilerOn = false;
protected int Max, Current;
protected boolean isDone, isGasOn, isPumpOn;
private temperatureUp tempUp;
private temperatureDown tempDown;

// Used to synchronize thread access to internal state (Current and 
// isBoilerOn member variables. The monitor is private in order
// for this class to encapsulate its synchronization policy.
private final Object monitor = new Object();

// update the bolier's status to on (true) or off (false)
public void setBoilerSatus(boolean status) {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        //  block threads until boiler is switched on
            this.isBoilerOn = status;
        // (see below), this is the place to notify them...
        notifyAll();
    }
}

// returns true if the boiler is on, false otherwise
public synchronized boolean getBoilerStatus() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        return this.isBoilerOn;           
    }
}

private void setGasBoilerStatus() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
    if(Max>Current)
        setBoilerSatus(true);
    else
        setBoilerSatus(false);
    }
}


class temperatureUp extends Thread 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    while(true)
    {
            try
            {
                increaseTemeture();                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(w));
                //txtLog.setText(w + "\n" + txtLog.getText());
            }
    }
    }
};

class temperatureDown extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                decreaseTemeture();                    
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
                ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(w));
                //txtLog.setText(w + "\n" + txtLog.getText());
            }
        }
    }
};
`
```

Comment: Can you include the exception stack trace please?

Comment: OP, for the next occasion at least try to grasp the concept "**throw an exception**".

Comment: what do you mean? when I put a beak line and try to trace the program, while its printing null, it goes to catching the exception line.

Comment: Elham, The **exception stacktrace** is the key diagnostic tool. You have instead shown us the word "null" repeated many times. We didn't learn anything from that.

Comment: ok, I updated the post again.

Comment: You get the exception because you are invoking method wait() in line 300 of sol.smarthome.GUI class, on an object whose monotor has not been acquired using synchronize().

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a class Thermostat that encapsulate's your thermostat's state and behaviors. The trick is to use proper synchronization in order to maintain your program's invariants. Below you may find a **sample** implementation of a Thermostat class based on your requirements description, **for illustration purposes**. Notice how synchronization is used in order to preserve your invariants. Any method (such as up(int) and down(int) which both affect the current temperature) may be invoked concurrently by different threads, without race events or related hazards due to synchronization.

Again, this is for illustration purposes only:

```
public final class Thermostat {

    // constant for maximum allowable temperature
    public static final int MAX_TEMP = 100;

    // the thermostat's current temperature
    private int temp = 0;

    // indicates if the boiler is on (true) or off (false)
    private boolean boilerStatus = false;

    public Thermostat() {

    }

    // Used to synchronize thread access to internal state (temp and 
    // boilerStatus member variables. The monitor is private in order
    // for this class to encapsulate its synchronization policy.
    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    // update the bolier's status to on (true) or off (false)
    public void setBoilerOn(boolean status) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            this.boilerStatus = status;
                    // if you block threads until boiler is switched on
                    // (see below), this is the place to notify them...         
        }
    }

    // returns true if the boiler is on, false otherwise
    public boolean isBoilerOn() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return this.boilerStatus;           
        }
    }

    // increase the thermostat's temperature by the specified units
    // provided that the boiler has been set on
    public void up(int units) {
        synchronized (monitor) {

            // don't increase the temperature if the boiler 
            // is not turned on...
            if (!isBoilerOn()) {
                            // you could alternatively wait here if your
                            // thread needs to block...
                return;
            }

            // increase the temperature 
            if ((temp + units) <= MAX_TEMP) {
                temp += units;                          
            } else {
                // TODO : handle incorect user input here...
            }
        }
    }

    // decrease the thermostat's temperature by the specified units
    // (negative values allowed)
    public void down(int units) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            temp -= units;          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's brilliant! let me try it out with details on my code. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: no prob. just bare in mind that this implementation does not block the temp increasing thread if the boiler is off. if you need for that thread to block, make sure you add the proper wait() and notifyAll() calls in the points i mention.

Comment: I'm confused again. see when I try to get the thread wait if (!isBoilerOn()) in up method, it tells me that I'm using wait command in an unsynchronized region! although it's inside the synchronized monitor object. why is this happening?

Comment: notice that in my example i synchronize on the monitor object, this means that i acquire its lock. wait() specifies that in order to be invoked on an object, you first need to acquire its lock using synchronized(). what you need to do in your case is invoke wait() on the monitor object (monitor.wait()). This will cause your current  execution thread to release the monitor object's lock and enter its wait set. Also, you need to make sure that any threads waiting on that monitor are notified when boiler is turned on. You do this by invoking monitori.notifyAll() after setting the boiler's status.

Comment: the monitor object is in charge of both decrease and increase right? so i added two thread one in charge of increasing and the other for decreasing and on the method I said if the GasBoiler is off the thread for tempUp should wait but I get the exception again. Please help!

Comment: In your updated code you acquire monitor instance's lock using synchronized(monitor) but you invoke wait() on tempUp instance. In order to invoke wait() on an object, you must acquire first the object's lock. What you need to do is monitor.wait().

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Full class name (dot) this`

eg:

```
notifyGasBoiler(MyTempClass.this);
```

Comment: The class is "public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame" when I put the class name, it creates error.

Comment: Tried using GUI.this;   I hope your this thread containing method is in this class itself

Comment: systemUpdater thread is a internal member defined in  formWindowActivated method so GUI class does not recognize it as a member you see.